# share a google docs with a specific user inside the domaine using service account

Tags: google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I can share a file or folder with a specific user inside the same domain `entreprise.tn` using the service account `master@entreprise.tn` through `Permessions`.

Could you please tell me if it's possible to share a google docs with a specific user ?.

Big thanks.

Comment: You say that you can "share a file or folder with a specific user inside the same domain". Is you question about how to share a file with a user outside of your domain?

Answer (score 0):

### To share a document with a specific user - can be domain-internal or external use the method [Permissions : create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

- What you need to do apart from providing the `fileId` is specify in the requestBody the parameters `role`, `type` and `emailAddress` correctly

[image]

- If you want to perform the erquest with the Service account, you have two options:

  - Give to the service account the necessary permissions for the file - only then is the service account authorized to share the file with other users
  - Use [impersonation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority), this allows the service account to act on behalf of the file owner, so you do not need to explicitly share the file with the service account